# Who was the man making the phony phone call?

Tags: plot-explanation, character, blindspot

I am watching the TV series [*Blindspot*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blindspot_(TV_series)) and I am currently on episode S02E13. If you have not watched until S02E09 then please do not read forward if you want to avoid spoilers.

In S02E09 a man makes a call to Weller to inform him that Allie had a serious car accident.

**My exact question: Should I, by S02E13, know (recognize) the man making the call?**

I just know that it was not Allie's boyfriend, as he was shortly shown a few episodes later and it was not the same person.

**PLEASE** format your answer the following way:

- if it was a random person without any link to the whole story, please state that
- if it was someone whom I should have recognized by S02E09 (or by S02E13 where I am now), please explain who that person was (I am not very good with recognizing faces, sorry if it was obvious)
- if this is someone who appears later, please try to use spoiler blocks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're referring to who I think you are, it was someone from the Sandstorm terrorist group who told Weller Allie was in an accident so he wouldn't be among the agents walking into the building rigged to blow. They didn't specify which member of Sandstorm made the call because it wasn't- storywise- important, just that the terrorist was acting on orders from Shepherd, who was fixated on Weller and his place in her 'new America'.

Comment: Thanks, I was wondering whether this was a generic member, or someone I should have explicitly recognized (important to the plot)